# Why do this function get a warning message from JSLint?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, jslint

I have a function that's working perfectly fine, but I still get a warning message from JS Lint.

```
            function undoActionClick() {
                if (history.length <= 1) return;
                history.pop();
                contextTmp.putImageData(history[history.length - 1], 0, 0);
                updateHistorySelection();
            }
```

This is the warning message: `Expected '{' and instead saw 'return'`. Is there an obvious error in the code, or should I just ignore the message?

Comment: Your linter is complaining about the single line if statement. Wrap it with `{}` or disable the rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function undoActionClick() {
    if (history.length <= 1) {
        return;
    }
    history.pop();
    contextTmp.putImageData(history[history.length - 1], 0, 0);
    updateHistorySelection();
}
```

This should be ok, it is not an error on your code but is wrong with one rule of `JSLint`.

More information in the [docs](https://jshint.com/docs/options/#curly)